# Possible to speed this while read bash script up?

Tags: shell-script, performance

I'm still VERY new to the whole linux bash scripting and I've come up with this little bit of code, unfortunately, its execution time is kinda long for a small file (193 KiB)

`real    0m7.234s
 user    0m6.772s
 sys     0m3.486s`

If you could take a look at it, pass some improvements or tips, would be appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while read line; do
    RNAME=$(echo $line | grep -w "ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation" | sed 's/^.*\(ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation.*\)/\1/g' | sed 's/".*//') 
    RSID=$(echo $line | grep -w "ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation" | grep -o "sid:.*" | awk '{print $1}' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev | cut -c 5-)
    echo $line | grep -w "ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation" | awk '{print  "'"$RSID"'" " " "\"[;][)]\"" " " "\"" "; fwsam: src[either], 1 hour;)\"; # " "'"$RNAME"'" }'#  >> /tmp/snortsam-rules.txt
    echo $line | grep -w "ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation" | awk '{print  "'"$RSID"'" " " "\"\\(msg:\"\" \"(msg:\"[SNORTSAM] \"; # " "'"$RNAME"'" }'  >> /tmp/snortsam-rules.txt
done < /etc/snort.d/rules/emerging-threats/emerging-ciarmy.rules
```

Contents of the Input file:

```
alert tcp [1.11.244.148,1.119.129.16,1.119.133.214,1.119.144.196,1.163.25.190,1.170.159.97,1.173.65.136,1.177.142.203,1.177.220.170,1.177.251.214,1.180.189.18,1.180.208.131,1.180.208.132,1.180.233.23,1.186.176.220,1.186.176.246,1.186.220.92,1.186.235.187,1.192.123.218,1.192.145.246,1.202.225.53,1.202.65.39,1.215.230.46,1.221.225.138,1.228.102.199,1.230.44.160,1.232.113.151,1.234.1.70,1.234.4.14,1.239.35.88,1.24.156.110,1.245.107.90,1.247.184.111,1.251.177.206,1.253.135.172,1.254.20.189,1.254.47.75,1.28.202.11,1.28.202.16,1.31.87.35,1.32.200.123,1.32.216.88,1.32.47.74,1.33.73.100,1.34.113.192,1.34.158.177,1.34.209.99,1.34.21.27,1.34.2.152,1.34.28.244] any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation IP TCP group 1"; flags:S; reference:url,www.cinsscore.com; reference:url,www.networkcloaking.com/cins; threshold: type limit, track by_src, seconds 3600, count 1; classtype:misc-attack; sid:2403300; rev:40471;)
```

Output Sample Code:

```
2403300 "[;][)]" "; fwsam: src, 1 hour;)"; # ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation IP TCP group 1
```

Basically, what i want to do is, take some parts of the input contents, and save them into a file, like the above output sample code, if that makes sense?

Comment: Show a sample of your input and your expected output.

Comment: You can eliminate the useless uses of echo with here strings. awk can search for strings as well so grep piped to awk is a useless use of grep.

Comment: For each line read, you call 14 programs.  Are you sure there's reason to complain?  Please add your sample to your question to make it readable.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Not sure i understand how I'm calling 14 programs. but I've updated my post

Comment: Grep, sed, awk, cut are programs.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

1. Reading individual lines from a file and the running multiple programs on each line multiple times is going be to excruciatingly slow.
2. See above for each time you do `echo $line | ...`.

Most of this can be done by awk itself:

```
awk -v fmt1='%s "[;][)]" "; fwsam: src, 1 hour;)"; # %s\n' -v fmt2='%s "\\(msg:"" "(msg:"[SNORTSAM] "; # %s\n' '/ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation/ {
  rname = gensub(/.*(ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation [^"]*).*/, "\\1", 1)
  rsid = gensub(/.*ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation.*sid:(.*); .*/, "\\1", 1)
  printf fmt1, rsid, rname
  printf fmt2, rsid, rname
}' input-file
```

Notes:

1. Instead of doing complex escaping to get a particular output format, use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Printf) with a format string. I Used two awk variables defined externally (`-v fmt1=...`, `-v fmt2=...`) as the format strings, thereby avoiding a lot of quoting.
2. You have used `echo ... | grep ... | awk` to print only if the `grep` pattern is matched. This is easily done in awk itself by using `/pattern/ { action }` to run actions only on lines matching the pattern.
3. The `rev | cut | rev | cut` and `sed ... | sed` commands' work is done easily enough in regex by keeping only the group of characters you need.

Comment: Isn't `rname` just set to the string `ET CINS...`?

Comment: @Kusalananda there seems to be a variable part after the fixed string we see in the post, up to a double quote character.

Comment: Ah, ok. That may well be the case. A bit difficult to see with only a sing line of input given.

Comment: It's `IP TCP group 1` in the example input (the part goes: `... any (msg:"ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation IP TCP group 1"; flags:S;  ...`)

Comment: @muru Thank you SO much! and thank you for so much info! i was reading into awk more, before your post, and i did see the `/pattern/ { action }` but couldn't wrap my head around it. After spending 40~ mins reading over the code you put forward, I'm getting the idea of how it works! again, thank you!

`real    0m0.090s | user    0m0.076s | sys     0m0.006s` compared to 
`real    0m7.234s | user    0m6.772s | sys     0m3.486s`